# "Unable to process request. Please try again later." when a registered information want to add in database by using netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, servlets

How do i auto-increase my id by 1, when I wany to save my registered information in my database from the register form? All the information is correct when want to validate and save in database. However, the cust id does not auto add in my database and state the error message.

[image]

[image]

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private EntityManagerFactory emf;

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();

        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String password = request.getParameter("conPass");
        String ic = request.getParameter("ic");
        String telno = request.getParameter("telno");
        String address = request.getParameter("address");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
       

        // Validate input fields
        if (name == null || name.trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name cannot be empty");
        }
        if (password == null || password.length() < 8) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Password must be at least 8 characters long");
        }
        if (ic == null || ic.trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("IC cannot be empty");
        }
        if (telno == null || telno.trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tel cannot be empty");
        }
        if (address == null || address.trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Address cannot be empty");
        }
        if (email == null || email.trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Email cannot be empty");
        }
        
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setCustname(name);
        customer.setPassword(password);
        customer.setCustic(ic);
        customer.setTelno(telno);
        customer.setAddress(address);
        customer.setEmail(email);
        

        em.persist(customer);

        transaction.commit();

        response.sendRedirect("complete.html");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Unable to process request. Please try again later.");
    }
}
```